# Which data structure to use instead of Arraylist in the given for and while loop?

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        Iterator<String> keys = jObject.keys();
        String key;
        JSONArray jsonArray;
        String value;
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            key = keys.next();
            countriesList.add(key);
            jsonArray = jObject.getJSONArray(key);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                value = jsonArray.getString(i);
                citiesList.add(value);
            }
            countryCities.put(key, citiesList);
            citiesList.clear();
```

Assume the following JSON file:

```
    {
  "China": [
    "Guangzhou",
    "Fuzhou",
    "Beijing"
  ],
  "Nepal": [
    "Pokhara",
    "Kathmandu",
    "Hetauda"
  ],
  "India": [
    "Delhi",
    "Mumbai",
    "Chennai"
  ]
}
```

There is a test method :

```
    private void CountriesListIterator(){

        ArrayList<String> country= countryCities.get("China");
        Log.d("Country size", String.valueOf(country.size()));


}
```

The  test method when called from onCreate() returns :`06-18 09:05:37.245 17603-17603/com.example.user.statusok D/Country size: 0`

The test method logs 0 because I have cleared the **citiesList** after I have put the **citiesList** in a HashMap. If I remove the **citiesList.clear()** line, the test method logs 9. **Is there a way in which if I run the test method it returns 3 instead of 0 or 9 ? What should I use instead of ArrayList to achieve the desired result?**

Comment: `Map<String, List<String>>` where key is the country and value is a list of cities.

Comment: I am using Map<String, ArrayList<String>  . Will implementing Map<String, List<String>> solve the problem ?

Comment: That won't, no. You should "program to the interface", though

Comment: Please edit your code to show a [mcve]. We should be able to copy-paste your code example and run it ourselves without any additional errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to create a new `ArrayList`, that way it will be a different reference; and the behavior will be as your probably expected. Change

```
citiesList.clear();
```

to

```
citiesList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Yes @cricket_007 provided the same solution. Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not clear. You're getting zero because you are.

When you don't, you're getting 9 because there's only ever one list you add to.

Both are a symptom of holding onto the same object reference.

You need to make a new ArrayList for every country

```
while (keys.hasNext()) {
    List<String> cities = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: But In my real JSON file , I have more than 200+ countries. So should I create different arraylist for each of them ?

Comment: Thanks a lot . I will tick this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

When you do `countryCities.put(key, citiesList);`, you add a **reference** to the list to your map. Since you reuse the same list, each reference points to the exact same list object. Instead, you need to create a new list of cities to add to the map. If you have many cities such that memory usage becomes a concern, you will also need to implement some kind of caching mechanism so that only a subset of your cities are loaded into memory at any given moment.

Comment: I think I will just add everything to a database upfront so that I do not have to repeat the same process of adding and creating list arraylists.

Comment: @SmithThapa that sounds like a reasonable solution